# jclouds/amazon s3/rackspace cloudfiles/windows azure storage- appending content to an existing blob

Tags: blob, jclouds

I have a scenario in which multiple lines of text are to be appended to an existing text file... Is it possible to do this using Jclouds? (That would be ideal for me as jclouds supports a lot of cloud providers)...

Even if this is not doable using jclouds, does the native API of Amazon S3/Rackspace Cloudfiles/Azure storage support appending content to existing blobs?

If this is doable, then kindly point me to good working examples which show the same...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the underlying blob stores I know of.